# Passing database value using <a href in laravel

Tags: php, html, laravel

I'm new to Laravel and working on my first project. I'm trying to delete a table row by passing its name through its delete link (a =href) to the route and then to the controller so I can run a mysql query to delete the row.

Here is the code for my table

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-highlight">
    <thead>
    <tr bgcolor="#c7c7c7">
        <th>Language</th>
        <th>Description</th>
        <th>Action</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    @foreach($getAllangLuages as $list)
    <tr>
        <td>{{$list->language_name}}</td>
        <td>{{$list->description}}</td>
        This is the issue->
        <td><a href="{{url('languages/deleterow')}}?{{$list->language_name}}">Delete</a></td>
    </tr>
    @endforeach
</table>
```

I'm trying to find the correct way to pass its name to the route and then finally to the controller.

can someone show me what to put in my route::? I'm having problems linking to it

Comment: add your route definition and controller code of delete functions

Answer (score 1):

If your route has a name then use [route](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/helpers#method-route) function and pass it the **id** as parameter

```
<a href="{{route('languages.deleterow',$list->id)}}">Delete</a>
```

else pass the **id** as the parameter to [url](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/helpers#method-url) method

```
<a href="{{url('languages/deleterow',$list->id)}}">Delete</a>
```

Comment: how about the route?

Comment: @styles9 what do u mean ?

Comment: to route it to my controller

Answer (score 1):

Maybe we can do in this way,this is what I am doing in my current project:

HTML

```
<a href="groups/delete/{{$groups['id']}}"><button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-circle " data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="" data-original-title="delete Groups"><i class="material-icons">remove_red_eye</i></button></a>
```

My Routes:

```
Route::get('/groups/delete/{id}','admin\GroupsController@getDeleteUsersGroups');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use route naming for a clean operation. [Laravel Routing](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/routing#named-routes)

```
Route::get('languages/deleterow/{name}', function ($name) {
    return App::make('LanguageController')->delete($name);
})->name('deleteLang');

<a href="{{ route('deleteLang', ['name' => $list->language_name]) }}">Delete</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

try this way :

```
<a href= "{{ url('languages/deleterow',['ID' => $list->language_name]) }}">{{ $list->language_name }}</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-highlight">
    <thead>
    <tr bgcolor="#c7c7c7">
        <th>Language</th>
        <th>Description</th>
        <th>Action</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    @foreach($getAllangLuages as $list)
    <tr>
        <td>{{$list->language_name}}</td>
        <td>{{$list->description}}</td>

        // Change This
        <td><a href="{{ route('languages.delete', $list->language_name) }}">Delete</a></td>

    </tr>
    @endforeach
</table>
```

Use [Named routes](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/routing#named-routes):

```
Route::GET('/languages/deleterow/{name}', 'YourController@methodName')->name('languages.delete');
```

Answer (score 0):

in web.php:

```
Route::get('delete/{id}','CategoryController@delete');
```

in blade file:

```
<a href = 'delete/{{$getAllangLuages ->id}}'><button type="button">Delete</button></a></td>
```